# Google colab not loading image files while using tensorflow 2.0 batched dataset

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

A little bit of background, I am loading about 60,000 images to colab to train a GAN. I have already uploaded them to Drive and the directory structure contains folders for different classes (about 7-8) inside `root`. I am loading them to colab as follows:

```
root = "drive/My Drive/data/images"
root = pathlib.Path(root)

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(root/'*/*'))

for f in list_ds.take(3):
  print(f.numpy())
```

which gives the ouput:

```
b'drive/My Drive/data/images/folder_1/2994.jpg'
b'drive/My Drive/data/images/folder_1/6628.jpg'
b'drive/My Drive/data/images/folder_2/37872.jpg'
```

I am further processing them as follows:

```
def process_path(file_path):
  label = tf.strings.split(file_path, '/')[-2]
  image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  return image#, label

ds = list_ds.map(process_path)

BUFFER_SIZE = 60000
BATCH_SIZE = 128

train_dataset = ds.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Each image is of size `128x128`. Now coming to the problem when I try to view a batch in colab the execution goes on forever and never stops, for example, with this code:

```
for batch in train_dataset.take(4):
  print([arr.numpy() for arr in batch])
```

Earlier I thought that batch_size might be a issue so tried changing it but still same problem. Can it be a problem due to colab as I am loading a large number of files?

Or due to the size of images as it was working when using MNIST(28x28)? If so, what are the possible solutions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After removing the shuffle statement, the last line gets executed within a few seconds. So I thought it could be a problem due to BUFFER_SIZE of shuffle, but even with a reduced BUFFER_SIZE, it is again taking a very long time to execute. Any workaround?

Comment: did you try to check if there is available gpu?

Comment: yes, I tried it with CPU as well as GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I load a 1.12GB zipped FLICKR image dataset from my personal Google Drive. First, I unzip the dataset in the colab environment. Some features that can speed up the performance is `prefetch` and `autotune`. Additionally, I use the local colab cache to store the processed images. This takes ~20 seconds to execute the first time (assuming you have unzipped the dataset). The cache then allows subsequent calls to load very fast.

Assuming you have authorized the google drive API, I start with unzipping the folder(s)

```
!unzip /content/drive/My\ Drive/Flickr8k
!unzip Flickr8k_Dataset
!ls
```

I then used your code with the addition of `prefetch()`, `autotune`, and `cache file`.

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf

def prepare_for_training(ds, cache, BUFFER_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE):
  if cache:
    if isinstance(cache, str):
      ds = ds.cache(cache)
    else:
      ds = ds.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE)
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  return ds

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

root = "Flicker8k_Dataset"
root = pathlib.Path(root)

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(root/'**'))

for f in list_ds.take(3):
  print(f.numpy())

def process_path(file_path):
  label = tf.strings.split(file_path, '/')[-2]
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  img =  tf.image.resize(img, [128, 128])
  return img#, label

ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = prepare_for_training(ds, cache="./custom_ds.tfcache", BUFFER_SIZE=600000, BATCH_SIZE=128)
for batch in train_dataset.take(4):
  print([arr.numpy() for arr in batch])
```

Here is a way to do it with keras `flow_from_directory()`. The benefit of this approach is that you avoid the tensorflow `shuffle()` which depending on the buffer size may require a processing of the whole dataset. Keras gives you an iterator which you can call to fetch the data batch and has the random shuffling built in.

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

root = "Flicker8k_Dataset"
BATCH_SIZE=128

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255 )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory = root,  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(128, 128),  # All images will be resized
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=42, #for the shuffle
        classes=[''])

i = 4
for batch in range(i):
  [print(x[0]) for x in next(train_generator)]
```

Comment: How long does the line `print([arr.numpy() for arr in batch])` take to execute for you?

Comment: And how big exactly is the dataset you are using?

Comment: 1.12 GB zipped, it takes 20 seconds regardless if I take take all or 4 in the loop

Comment: @bkshi Did you try the Tensorflow data?

Comment: I was talking about the second code snippet in my answer. I have updated it to load MNIST from tensorflow's servers instead of a Google Drive folder

Comment: The1st code is  working for MNIST but I have problem loading the custom dataset that I have in my drive.

Comment: I see, I have updated the answer to reflect my whole process now. I think you would benefit from zipping your dataset in your drive to unzip it in the colab environment.

Comment: I already used it with both zipped and unzipped and cachin also doesn't help! Anything else I need to check?

Comment: I tried removing shuffle and it executed within a few seconds. But then I tried with a reduced shuffle size and it is again taking too long! Any work around for this?

Comment: Yeah, shuffle would force it to work through the whole dataset. I updated my answer to use a method from keras that flows data from the directory and has the shuffled selection implemented in its background. Let me know if that works.